How to solve TypeError of getFullYear() function with devextreme Datebox?
Recently, I encountered an issue which the devextreme-react date-box cannot change its value with onValueChanged function, and it returns the below error:
Uncaught TypeError: t.getFullYear is not a function
    at w (dx.all.js:19:2246625)
    at x (dx.all.js:19:2246540)
    at Object.sameDate (dx.all.js:19:2249338)
    at t._valueChangedHandler (dx.all.js:19:1580825)
    at Object.execute (dx.all.js:19:2166269)
    at l._executeAction (dx.all.js:19:2165470)
    at l.execute (dx.all.js:19:2165081)
    at t.<anonymous> (dx.all.js:19:2173158)
    at t.l [as _valueChangeAction] (dx.all.js:19:2173871)
    at t._raiseValueChangeAction (dx.all.js:31:453687)

This is the sample code that I tested with it:
function App() {
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState<string>("");

  const onDateValueChanged = (e: ValueChangedEvent) => {
    setDateValue(e.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <DateBox
        type="datetime"
        dateSerializationFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        isRequired={true}
        isDisabled={false}
        isReadonly={false}
        value={dateValue}
        onValueChanged={onDateValueChanged}
        max={new Date()}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


Just to confirm, you're using <DateBox ...> instead of <Datebox ...> right?

@thecosmicintrovertdude yeah, my bad; it's a typo, let me change it real quick.

I've tried checking the documentation. Instead of treating the dates as string can you do do it as Date object itself and see if it works?

Why this happens?
I'm assuming the DateBox library is calling the getFullYear on Date internally. While Date object has this method, strings don't - hence your code is crashing.
Give me a fix

At first, change the state to use Date object instead of string.

const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(new Date(1981, 3, 27));

Note (from your comments): It seems like setting null as default value also works. This is probably because null quite represents empty value - and they might be using placeholders to cover it up.
So simply, you can do this:
const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(null);


Update the onDateValueChanged callback:

  const onDateValueChanged = useCallback((e: DateBoxTypes.ValueChangedEvent) => {
    setDateValue(e.value);
  }, []);

Hope this helps.

Thank you, and the first method works; the documentation said I could set it as string but it appears to have some issues. What if I want to initialise it without a date?

Well, I'm assuming that the DateBox is internally calling the getFullYear method on the changed value - as Date object has this method it works pretty fine - but strings don't have this and that's probably why you're getting this exception in the first place. I'm kind of not sure why they say in the documentation it can be string. Well, if you want to use string values - I'd say you can simply create a utility function to convert Date to formatted string. That'll be a good way around :)

Okay, I have tried initialising it as null and it seems to be working; it looks like an empty string is treated with weird behaviours. The null and Date combination works. Thank you for the inspiration.

Would you mind updating the answer so I could mark it as accepted? Great thanks!

Glad it worked, updated my answer :) Happy coding!
